# Quality not Quantity Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality

There is a user on a Stack Exchange site where I am heavily active who seems to post a great deal of poor answers. Here are some vote stats:

```
67 Answers

14 between (-1) - (-4) inclusive
23 (0)    
20 (1)
10 (2) - (6) inclusive

1 accepted answer

Update - As of this afternoon the user in question has now hit a (-9)
```

These range over a period of two weeks since the user first joined the site. Gradually there have been more and more answers on questions that already have an Accepted answer and these answers don't add anything else compared to the previously listed answers.

Far be it from me to say this user is posting crap answers as it's not my place. But how would a SE site deal with something such as this? Is it a Moderator thing to be concerned about or the community to do something about it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a self-correcting problem. Too many poorly-scoring answers and the user will find himself unable to post any more answers, due to the automatic post-ban.

What the community should do is to keep downvoting poor answers.

See: [Answer bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)

> Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban answers from accounts that have contributed many low-quality answers in the past. These filters help keep the quality of our sites high. The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts. One or two bad posts will not cause you to to be blocked from using the site.

Comment: And if he want to get rid of answer ban he has to improve his previous answers which have downvotes.

Comment: Ahh - I didn't know we had an A-ban to go with the Q-ban.  I'm glad we do, though

Answer (score -9):

The voting mechanism is very relevant to reflect posts quality, but is not 100% accurate though.

In my opinion, the down-voting mechanism should be somehow reviewed.

Here are some patterns (that happened to me personally) and probably more are out here, for what I consider **non deserved down-vote**:

- The person didn't understand my question
- The person didn't understand my answer
- The person didn't *like* my answer (answers of type: You cannot do that...)

Also when I see for some of posts (9 up votes & against 1 down-vote), is a reason to believe that that down-vote should not be there.

Comment: "*The person didn't understand my question*" That's almost always your fault. It's incumbent upon you to explain your question clearly and justify it. Garbage in, garbage out. "*The person didn't understand my answer*" Ditto. "*The person didn't like my answer (answers of type: You cannot do that...)*" I have rarely seen downvoting for this unless the answer was *wrong*. For example, claiming that "you cannot do that" when you very much *can*.